# Running ANT script for jdk 1.8 and JavaFX in Eclipse 2022-06 release

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I need to build a javaFX application running on jdk 1.8 in Eclipse 2022-06.
I have installed e(fx)clipse v 3.7.0 (trying to upgrade to 3.8.0 fails).

ANT won't work on jdk newer than 9 or 11, so the build scripts complains that javafx packages do not exist.

Is there a way to work with Java 8 and JavaFX in the latest Eclipse release ?

Thank you!

Comment: It would likely come to your jdk system environment variables, although you could go into the eclipse configure menu and add the info required for use of either ant  or another jdk version.

Comment: The ant built in to Eclipse works fine with Java 18. Later versions of Java don't include the JavaFX code, it has to be downloaded separately.

Comment: @greg-449 How do I tell ANT how to find the javafx libs ? I have to change ANT HOME to jdk11. If I set it to jdk8, the build won't run. But as jdk11 does not have javafx, how do I link ANT to javafx?

Comment: Once you have downloaded JavaFX you tell the `javac` task in your ant build about it using the `classpath` argument like you would for any other jar. The [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info) for  the javafx tag has lots of info and links

Comment: Does Ant need JavaFX for itself, or to compile your code against?

Comment: Thanks @greg-449, I added the files to the build.xml file for the javac task and it got me to the next obstacle :) 
"Can not find JDK artifacts in specified location"
Unfortunately, I think I need jdk11 at this point but cannot use it as I have 32-bit dll dependencies and jdk11 packages only come in 64-bit flavor.

Comment: @nitind I am trying to build a JavaFX app, I don't think ant needs JavaFX to operate

Comment: “jdk11 packages only come in 64-bit flavor” -> You can get 32 bit JDK and JavaFX packages for recent distributions from multiple vendors. For example [BellSoft Liberica 32 bit “Full JDK” 18](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/#/java-18-current) for Windows and Linux.  Or Azul Zulu JDK FX 18 32 bit.  If it were me, I wouldn’t waste time and effort with obsolete distributions and build tools.